# Resume and Pause while uploading file to GCS in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, resume, pause

I tried [this](https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage) code for uploading files on GCS in android . This code is running perfectly and uploading file on bucket. But now I want to upload file in background(from service) with Pause/Resume functionality, which will Pause when internet connection will gone and Resume when internet connection available.. I search alot on internet but did not find any perfect solution.

```
CloudStorage.uploadFile("upload-recording", "/storage/sdcard0/Download/images.jpg",this,file);

public static void uploadFile(String bucketName, String filePath,Context context,File file_use)
            throws Exception {

        this_context = context;
        this_file = file_use;
        Storage storage = getStorage();

        StorageObject object = new StorageObject();
        object.setBucket(bucketName);

        File file = new File(filePath);

        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            String contentType = URLConnection
                    .guessContentTypeFromStream(stream);
            InputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent(contentType,
                    stream);

            Storage.Objects.Insert insert = storage.objects().insert(
                    bucketName, null, content);
            insert.setName(file.getName());

            insert.execute();
        } finally {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload read under "Resumable upload".

Comment: @Christine thankyou for the response. I already go through it but I want java implementation.